# Why do we need fields value in Meta class in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

If I have 3 fields in my Form class and in `fields` I set only one field, on my html page still will be 3 fields.

Example:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                           help_text='Please enter the category name.')
    views = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

So `fields` variable doesn't hide anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The generated Form class will have a form field for every model field specified, **in the order specified** in the **fields** attribute."

If you want to hide fields, use

```
exclude = ('views','likes','slug')
```

I highly recommend you to take a look at the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use